# rooted android JB 4.1.1 razr m , Map network drive with VPN

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, networking, vpn, motorola-droid-razr, openvpn

So I established a VPN using openVPN app on my phone. My phone has an IP and everything on the network. What I would like to do now is browse the network drives remotely and possibly download files to my phone or open them using quick office. Is this possible?? I have done a bit of research but all the questions concerning mapped network drives are for computers.

I usually just use "net use" in my .bat file to automatically connect to network drives with a user name and password when I have a VPN running for the same network on my laptop.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check out this superuser link: http://superuser.com/questions/145191/how-do-i-map-a-drive-network-share-using-the-linux-terminal